# Visitor latitude & longitude geolocation value send to Controller Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

How do i get value latitude and longitude Geolocation for my controller value variable?

Here's my geolocation code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(setPosition);
        } else {
            console.log("Geolocation not supported by browser.");
        }

    }

    function setPosition(position) {
        console.log(position);
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ route('home.index') }}",
            data: {
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude
            },
            success: function(ajax) {
                console.log($.ajax);
            },
            error: function(request, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

and here's my Controller Method Index (as front page/main page):

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {

        $latitude = $request->latitude;
        $longitude =  $request->longitude;

        // $latitude = "-6.190054983260954";
        // $longitude = "106.79885292237778";

        $posts = Blog::where('is_active', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(3);
        $products = Product::where('is_active', '1')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(6);

        $pharmacies = DB::table("pharmacies");

        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->select(DB::raw("id, pharmacy_name, pharmacy_address, pharmacy_thumbnail, pharmacy_excerpt, pharmacy_description, pharmacy_phone, pharmacy_wa, pharmacy_gmap, SQRT(POW(($latitude - pharmacy_lat ), 2) +
        POW(($longitude - pharmacy_long), 2)) * 111.319 AS
        distance"));

        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->having('distance', '<', 50);
        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->orderBy('distance', 'asc');

        $pharmacies = $pharmacies->paginate(3);


        return view('pages.index', [
            'posts' => $posts,
            'products' => $products,
            'pharmacies' => $pharmacies,

        ]);
    }
```

How do i get latitude and longitude value geolocation and pass it to my Controller?
I tried so many ways, and when i do `dd($latitude);` or `dd($langitude);` it gave me null, not value longitude and latitude from geolocation

Any ways to solve this?

Comment: what do you see where you `console.log(position)`?

Comment: It show longitude and latitude value

Comment: so, you're using GET, so the request in the browser is something like `https://host.com/path-to-your-endpoint?longitude=123&latitude=45` right? - does the server expect the lat/long in the request URL search?

Comment: Yes right, i don't know that yet.. how to make it?

Comment: you don't know that? well, what request DOES your browser make? What DOES **your** server expect? It's your code, can you explain what it expects?

Comment: My browser does request get, but my server i guess i haven;t make that yet.. i new at this, so my knowledge not that much..

Comment: `Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');` is this server expects?

Answer (score 1):

I try your code in my local server. It works fine to get `lat`, `logn` of a location. But the problem is in your route and `ajax` method call. I update your code like below and it is working fine in my local

```
Route::post('/location', [App\Http\Controllers\ HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');
```

On your view page just add a line any where

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf-token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

In your `ajax` request like below

```
function setPosition(position) {
    console.log(position);
    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    var csrf = $("#csrf-token").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "{{ route('home.index') }}",
        data: {
            _token:         csrf,
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        },
        success: function(ajax) {
            console.log($.ajax);
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Wow! Very appreciate it.. But, do i have to make other Controller? Because i have to use long, lat value to calculat in HomeController method index..

Comment: I tried in my local `LocationController` but it should be your `Controller` name and your `url` name. I don't know your `route`

Comment: Oke, so i change it.. and access http://127.0.0.1:8080/location and give me this error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: Do i have to remove /location to only / in route? because i want in my main page

Comment: @SutanFirqy, Please share your `route`

Comment: `Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');`
`Route::post('/location', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home.index');` This is my route

Comment: Ok. I understand your problem. You want  user's `lat`, `long` if a user visit your home page. For location, you have to write a new `route` like below
`Route::post('/location', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'location'])->name('home.location');`

Comment: If so, do i have to make another method in my Home Controller and change `url: "{{ route('home.index') }}",` in ajax to `route('home.location')` ?

Comment: I try what you suggested to add another route, add new method, and change ajax url.. But still gave me this error `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` I really need your help..

Comment: I think so. You have to use your `ajax` request from `pages.index` blade view

Comment: Plese execute this command `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Oke, i might have to get this clear for make specific scope my goal.. My case is when user allow location, my geolocation code will get user long and lat value, and from that value, i want to pass that value to my controller, so that long and lat value can be use as value to my method variable for calculate nearest place from user..

Comment: Yes i did route:clear.. but still `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.`

Comment: You have to use `ajax` method `POST` and `route` should be `Route::post(...)`. It is working fine for me

Comment: I did, `Route::post('/location', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'location'])->name('home.location');` and ajax `type: 'POST',` but still got that error

Comment: Did you write your `url` like `url: "{{ route('home. location') }}",`?

Comment: Yes, in ajax i write url like that `url: "{{ route('home.location') }}"`

Comment: If you want you will share your remote access like `anydesk`. I can't believe why this error occur

Comment: Do you have discord? can we discuss at discord?

Comment: I use your code in my own project. It is working perfectly. Plz share your mobile number if you agree.

Comment: How do i chat you personally in stackoverflow to share my number?

Comment: @SutanFirqy, In WhatApp we may personal conversation